# i want to add checkbox in table view which grows dynamically and perform operations in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-2, javafx-8

Actually i want to add checkbox to this table view which grows dynamically and with the help of a check box i want to delete the data from the database. How to add checkbox in this dynamic table.
Thank you in advance

```
public class CheckEngineDetailMain extends Application{

//TABLE VIEW AND DATA
private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
private TableView tableview;
//MAIN EXECUTOR
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

//CONNECTION DATABASE
public void buildData(){

    Connection c ;
      data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      try{
        c = DBConnect.connect();

        //SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF CUSTOMER

        String SQL = "SELECT * from Engine_Detail_test;" ;

        //ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        /**********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
         **********************************/
        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;                
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                }                    
            });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col); 

            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
        }



        while(rs.next()){
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //Iterate Column
                //row.add(1, new CheckBox());
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);

        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        tableview.setItems(data);
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
      }
  }


  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    //TableView

    tableview = new TableView();
    buildData();

    //Main Scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(tableview);        

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, it is quite bad idea to mix all things, like the main class with the controller, and not using `.fxml` file(s) is also a bad practice, but, the solution your problem is that you have to set a `cellFactory` to your column that you want to be the "mark for delete" or "delete" column.
So for example this way after the for loop:

```
TableColumn col = new TableColumn("column header name you want");
col.setCellFactory(factory -> new CheckBoxTableCell());
col.setCellValueFactory(v -> {
        BooleanProperty property = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        property.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                tableView.getItems().remove(((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures)v).getValue());
            }
        });
    return property;
});
tableView.getColumns().add(col);
```

Then you have to make the tableView editable this way : `tableView.setEditable(true);`. This makes the whole table editable, if you want to be editable just the last column you can simply put in your for loop 
        `col.setEditable(false);`

P.S. also a bad practice not using a separate model class for holding the rows' data, and another bad practice not using generics for example at `TableView<here you should put the type of your model>`